# Custom Site Font Ignored By SVG

Tags: css, svg, fonts

PROBLEM: Custom font not recognized by svg image on a web page, if it is not installed in operating system.

RESEARCH: On a site I have a custom font at [kombinezonik.ru/fonts/futuris/FuturisC.otf](http://kombinezonik.ru/fonts/futuris/FuturisC.otf). In CSS I define it before any other definitions as follows:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: FuturisC;
  src: 
    local('FuturisC'),
    url("/fonts/futuris/FuturisC.otf")    ;
}

tr.navig a#hrefb37 {
  width: 85px;
  height: 42px;
  background-size: 70px 35px;
  background-image: url('/images/navig_b37.png');  
  background-image: url('/images/navig_b37.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

My [SVG-image](http://kombinezonik.ru/images/navig_b37.svg) is:

```
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  viewBox="0 0 145.683 84.904">
  <text
    y="26.982203"
    x="73.03183"
    style="
      font-weight:normal;
      font-size:40px;
      font-family:FuturisC;
      text-align:center;
      text-anchor:middle;"
    xml:space="preserve"><tspan 
    y="26.982203" x="73.03183">Мальчики</tspan><tspan 
    y="76.982201" x="73.03183">3-7 лет</tspan></text>
</svg>
```

QUESTION: How to apply the FuturisC.otf font to [the SVG image](http://kombinezonik.ru/images/navig_b37.svg)?

Comment: How are you including the SVG in the page? Are you inlining it in the HTML, or using `<img>`, or something else?

Comment: I assume you've read http://nimbupani.com/about-fonts-in-svg.html ("put the CSS in the SVG code"), so: did that not work?

Comment: SVG is included via CSS as s background-image. Added fragment to question. As for nimbupani.com/demo/svgfonts/svg-fontface.svg - I change the "src: url" on any other .otf font even manually in chrome debugger and nothing happens.